# Регулярные выражения, проверить введенные данные

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста помогите проверить введенные данные. Необходимо чтобы поле "Регион" содержало только кириллицу, возможны так же пробелы и знак дефис. От 2 до 50 символов.

```
if (preg_match("/^[А-Яа-я- ]{2,50}$/", $region)) {
    echo "Поле Регион заполнено верно.";
} else {
    echo "Поле Регион заполнено не верно";
}
```

В данном случае что бы я не вводила - выдает сообщение "Поле Регион заполнено не верно"

Comment: Надо ещё `Ёё` отдельно в выражение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Попробуйте добавить модификатор **u** (Unicode)
2. В символьных классах общепринято ставить тире впереди всего.

   ```
   /^[-А-Яа-я ]{2,50}$/u
   ```

Comment: Тоже `Ёё` пропустил.

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```
$region="Авап пр- ";
if (preg_match("/[^-А-Яа-я ]+/msi", $region)) {
    echo "Поле Регион заполнено не верно.";
} else {
    echo "Поле Регион заполнено верно";
}
```

Comment: в принципе, пробелы можно разрешить.
и + не нужен, по идее.
и если `i`, наверное, заглавные буквы не нужны? (не уверен)

Comment: конечно заглавные буквы не нужны. А еще человек не знает, как работает знак ^ в регулярных выражениях, раз исключает все символы выражения в скобках. Осторожней!

Comment: Спасибо, будем крепить (-: